# Populate label based on combobox vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the below code populating my combo box, however I want to populate a label with the second database column from the select statement below.

I'm struggling to understand how to complete this? Is this the correct direct to complete the task?

```
        da.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT [ShopDesc], [ShopCode] FROM fg_tbl_Shop_List", conn)
    da.Fill(dt)

    Dim r As DataRow
    For Each r In dt.Rows
        com_Shop_List.Items.Add(r("ShopDesc").ToString)
        lbl_ShopCode.Text = com_Shop_List.Items.Add(r("ShopCode").toint)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to populate a label with the second

You can use a label control to display any text. You could not populate it by some data and next time you have no option to choose one of them from a label like a combobox or a listBox. Just to show any string type data.

```html
Label1.Text = "Your String Value"
```

Comment: Sorry - I should of explained it better.  I want to present column 2 in the lbl based on the item selected from the combo box that is pulled from a database

Comment: Why are you posting the same answer twice, and using code snippets doesn't work with server side coding.

Answer (score 0):

On selection from combobox you can try the following codes.

```html
Private Sub com_Shop_List_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles com_Shop_List.SelectedIndexChanged
    
  Dim r As DataRow
  For Each r In dt.Rows
    If r.Item("[ShopDesc]") = com_Shop_List.Items(com_Shop_List.SelectedIndex) Then
      lbl_ShopCode.Text = r.Item("[ShopCode]")
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Why are you pasting VB.net as a snippet?  The snippets are specifically for client side code not server side.

Comment: Do not understand your question. I am new in stackoverflow. Do not know all manners. Pls. describe, it would be helpful to me.

Comment: When you post code use the code tag, when you post a script like simple css/js script you can use the script snippet.